# Use XCode and ESP8266 as run destination

Tags: ios, xcode, esp8266

I'm using XCode to manage an IOT project on a ESP8266 board.

XCode is nice because it very well manages the syntax coloring, the source configuration etc. And it is also nice to have one single environment for the ESP8266 part of the project as well as the iOS part.

I have also modified the build script for the ESP8266 target so that it calls the right compiler, and errors are directly shown in the code. Works nice.

The only thing I couldn't find how to do in XCode build system is how to flash the ESP8266 board when I want to **run** the code. Something like define a "Run Destination" that is not an Apple platform, as well as listen to the serial link to log messages in the console.

Is it even possible ?